# Select a record using a date between the same colum

Tags: sql

If I have a table with the following records:

```
ID    Load       Type
=====================
1  10/01/2013     A
2  10/21/2013     A
3  10/30/2013     A
```

I need a select statement to retrieve the following scenario:

I have a date of 10/25/2013, record 2 would be retrieved. Or date of 10/01/2013 record 1 would be retrieved. Or date >= 10/30/2013 I would get record 3.

Comment: Are you asking or telling us?

Comment: You should address a specific programming language question - please read the manual - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: There's no question being asked here. What have you tried to do so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using SQL Server...

```
SELECT TOP 1 * from [TableName]
WHERE [Load] >= @date
ORDER BY [Load] DESC
```

Comment: I was making this harder then it needed to be. Thanks Arkiliknam. Only change would be Load <= @date. Thanks again.